# requests with https proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, python-requests

I am using python requests to load a page using https proxy but its not working. The same code is working with http proxy.

The following is my code:

With https proxy

```
import requests
proxyDict = {'https': 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx'}
r = requests.get('http://icanhazip.com', proxies=proxyDict)
print(r)
print(r.content)
```

> Output:
>
> Response [200]
>
> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - the ip is for my server and not the proxy server

With http proxy

```
import requests
proxyDict = {'http': 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx'}
r = requests.get('http://icanhazip.com', proxies=proxyDict)
print(r)
print(r.content)
```

> Output:
>
> Response [200]
>
> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - the ip is for proxy server

How to use **https proxy server with python requests**?

Is there any error in my code? Or how to fix this issue?

Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code example, you are using HTTPS proxy but making a request to HTTP site. You should do `r = requests.get('https://icanhazip.com', proxies=proxyDict)` instead.

Comment: Ya that's what I also figured out after testing yesterday. Thanks for help @Rytis